# Android 4.4 HTML apple-touch-icon not working?

Tags: android, html, mobile

When people like to make an shortcut on their smartphone to my webapp they need to see an icon of my app. The method that i need to use is this one:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="external/afbeeldingen/apple-touch-icon.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="external/afbeeldingen/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
```

This works fine on android 4.2 and lower and the Iphone. But when trying this on newer Android versions it shows an default icon instead of my webapp icon.

Did i do something wrong or is this an Android bug..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try also adding the favicon as a PNG at 196 pixels like so:

`<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="196x196" href="icon-196x196.png">`

Taken from [here.](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/home-screen-web-apps-android-chrome-31)